# Data Flow Task Buffer Size

Tags: ssis

I have created a package to pull more than 200,000 records. The pulling performance is bit slow. To increase the performance ie faster how much **DefaultMaxRows** and **DefaultBufferSize** should I have to give ? How do we set the buffer ? is there any calculation ?

Comment: What is it pulling from?

Comment: Firstly its pulling from Oracle DB. Then from SQL Server where the pulling the getting slow itself !!!!

Comment: What's CPU load and memory usage when it's going slow? What other transformations are you doing when it's going slow? Is it pulling from remote or local data? All these things can affect performance, and without knowing more details in advance, it'd be just guessing what the problem is.

Comment: its pulling from local. And transformations used are Lookup, Conditional Split and OLE DB Command when going slow

Answer (score 0):

SSIS does a descent job in optimizing the performance .For the Better Buffer performance , u can remove unwanted column from the source and set the data type for each column appropriately depending upon the source value .

However if u change the value of the Buffer size , it can have adverse effect on the performance (Page spoiling begins ) .

However You can try  enabling logging of the BufferSizeTuning event to learn how many rows a buffer contains .Sometimes setting them to a higher value can boost performance, but only as long as all buffers fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, the simple answer is:

Do not use OLE DB Command if you want speed. OLE DB Command needs to execute once per row. If you want to load 200,000 records that also means 200,000 executions of your OLE DB Command.

Perhaps you can explain what your ole db command does, and we can find a faster solution?

Comment: I am using OLE DB Command for updating rows at destination table

Comment: Then you'll issue one update per row, which doesn't sound fast. You could look into storing the new data in a table using the OLE DB Destination, then run a MERGE statement using a SQL Command task in your control flow. This would probably yield better performance (given that you are on 2008 or newer)